# Error message when using NextAuth and Firebase Auth: POST https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:lookup?key=API_KEY 400

Tags: firebase-authentication, next-auth

When users sign in or sign up to my Next.js app, I keep seeing an error message in the console that says:

> POST https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:lookup?key=API_KEY 400

I am using NextAuth and Firebase Auth in my code. Here's an example of how I'm setting up NextAuth with GoogleProvider:

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
      authorizationUrl:
        "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?prompt=consent&access_type=offline&response_type=code",
      headers: {
        "User-Agent":
          "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36",
      },
    }),
  ],
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

And here's an example of how I'm initializing Firebase in my code:

```js
import { getApp, getApps, initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "API_KEY",
  authDomain: "AUTH_DOMAIN",
  databaseURL: "DATABASE_URL",
  projectId: "PROJECT_ID",
  storageBucket: "STORAGE_BUCKET",
  messagingSenderId: "MESSAGING_SENDER_ID",
  appId: "APP_ID",
  measurementId: "MEASUREMENT_ID",
};

const app = getApps().length ? getApp() : initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const auth = getAuth(app);
export { db, auth };
```

I am also using Firebase Admin SDK in my code:

```js
import admin from "firebase-admin";

const serviceAccount = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY);
if (!admin.apps.length) {
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  });
}

const adminDb = admin.firestore();
const adminAuth = admin.auth();

export { adminDb, adminAuth };
```

Can someone please help me fix this error message?